# Envio de correo duplicado desde android studio

Tags: android-studio, phpmailer

estoy teniendo un problema al enviar un correo desde mi aplicacion de android, uso phpmailer para hacer el envio, al hacer la peticion, el correo llega pero me llega 3 veces seguido, si ejecuto mi php desde postman, ahi no tengo problema.
Aqui el codigo desde android studio:

```
    private void envioCorreoCierre(String UrlEncuesta){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(UrlEncuesta, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {                
            Toast.makeText(observaciones.this, "Notificación enviada" + " " + codigoRespuesta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de conexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

En el boton lo mando llamar de esta manera:

```
    btn_enviaCorreo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            envioCorreoCierre("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/servicios/EnviaMail.php?idServicio=" + ET_idServicio.getText() + "");               
        }
    });
```

Agradezco sus aportes.

Comment: Hola. Con el código que compartes no podemos ver por qué se envía varias veces. ¿No será que en otra parte del programa llamas al método de envío varias veces? ¿No será que en el código del servidor haces el envío varias veces? Sin ver eso, nada podremos decirte. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, ya complemente la pregunta, agregue el codigo que tengo en el boton. Por el lado del codigo PHP he echo la prueba ejecutando con Postman y ahi no tengo problema, solo llega una vez el correo.

Comment: En primer lugar, **verifica en el gradle que tienes una versión actualizada de Volley**, pues algunas versiones antiguas tenían un problema de enviar la petición varias veces. Actualizando la versión de Volley debería corregirse ese problema. Si persiste después de haber actualizado, agrega esto: **`jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`** justo antes de esta línea: `requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);`

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por el apoyo. Se corrigio agregando la linea: DefaultRetryPolicy(0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Comment: Me alegro. De todos modos, revisa tu versión de Volley, pues ese problema no debería existir en una versión actualizada. OJO: me parece que hay una biblioteca Volley que no es la oficial, espero que no estés usando esa.

Comment: en el gradle lo mando llamar asi: implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1' revise en github y esa es la version mas reciente que encontre. a menos que la implementacion de volley es incorrecta.

Comment: Esa es la biblioteca correcta, es que hay bibliotecas hechas por terceros con las que algunos se confundían en el pasado, al poner `com.android` estamos seguros de que es la correcta y tienes la última versión. Entonces es raro que te pase eso, yo usé Volley en el pasado y no tuve nunca ese problema. Aunque lo que mejor funciona para peticiones remotas es Retrofit, además, se adecúa a código escrito basado en arquitectura limpia, por ejemplo si quieres implementar el patrón MVVM, que es hacia donde Android está apuntando actualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según se reporta en algunos grupos, versiones anteriores de Volley tenían el problema de enviar las peticiones varias veces, [ver aquí por ejemplo](https://groups.google.com/g/volley-users/c/8PE9dBbD6iA) y ver también [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27873001/5587982) en el homólogo inglés de este sitio.

Lo primero que debes revisar es si estás implementando la biblioteca correcta de Volley así como [la versión más actualizada](https://github.com/google/volley/releases/tag/1.2.1), que al momento de esta respuesta es la `1.2.1`, por tanto, deberías tener esto:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
}
```

Si ya tienes una versión actualizada y el problema persiste, entonces limita los reintentos de la petición, aplicando una política de reintentos adecuada:

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    0,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```